# Ubuntu terminal email client

Tags: software-recommendation, email

I am looking for an email client in the form of a terminal/console application. Does such an app exist on Ubuntu 14.04? I've yet to find one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mutt is a fairly popular text-based CLI email client that you can run in Ubunutu (and other distros).  Get it with

```
sudo apt-get install mutt
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is also alpine.

`sudo apt-get install alpine`